# When to use SysFs interface

Tags: interface, module, kernel, using, sysfs

I have requirement to provide the user space API for a Kernel module, where the kernel module is interacting with devices using I2C and SPI interfaces. I have implemented kernel module which exposes the ProcFs interface for the user space. I have also developed a userspace application to interact with KernelModule via ProcFS. This is all working fine.

Can I use the SYSFs interface in place of procfs ? which is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to the same question, and I found some resources that may help to clarify in case someone visits here in the future.

First, a link to a resource: http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto-2.html

If anyone has a better understanding, please correct me but what I understood is that procfs is depreciated and should not be used unless you are simply trying to communicate information from/to your process.